# Can I use the same AFR sensor on both banks (bank 1 sensor 1 and bank 2 sensor 1)

Tags: o2-sensor, maf

Have 1mzfe

(skip this paragraph if you don't want backstory)
codes p1135/p1130/whatever the ones for the other bank are/ all showed up at the same, perfect time. ie when I was broke. Since then car will stutter when warm (I assume it's only when warm because it enters closed loop fuel control then). Car doesn't do it when I pull the MAF. Through my wonderful deductive powers (which pretty much equate to googleing the problem and following simple steps) I am like 94% certain the AFR sensors are bad (and maybe that MAF? but that's another question I suppose)

Need new upstream AFR sensors (both banks)
both sensors are on the exhaust manifold of each respective bank.

Can I use the same sensor for both banks? ie can I just order 2 or is there a slightly different but important other part ##?

http://shop.advanceautoparts.com/p/denso-air-fuel-sensor-direct-fit-234-9021/20471861-P?searchTerm=air+fuel+ratio+sensor

eg can I just order two of these and b gud?

Also, any recommendation on engine mount brand, are these things

> OEM or enjoy your vibration
>   ?

Comment: AFR woes can be deceptive. If you're getting codes for both banks all of a sudden,b I'm inclined to believe that the issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: Wanted to post an update since your comment was nearly prophetic in accuracy. Issue actually ended up being a break in the AFR heater circuit from the fuse to the positive battery terminal. I had a long and very fun thread on the ETCG forums that's readable here if anyone wants to learn from my mistakes and save themselves $300 in sensors.


http://www.ericthecarguy.com/kunena/8-Service-and-Repair-Questions-Answered-Here/53145-p1130-p1133-p1150-p1153-on-2000-lexus-es300

Comment: I can imagine that was fun to hunt down :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cars, they are exactly the same between banks 1 & 2. In fact in a lot of cars, you could use the down stream sensors as the upstream sensors (this all assumes OBD2). So, yes, order exact for both sides.

Secondly, the reason your car runs better when you pull the MAF is the same reason it runs the way it does in open loop. When you pull the MAF, the computer goes to speed density and open loop mode.